# I am NOT merging a data set. Why does R keep saying "names do not match previous names"?

Tags: r, names

I am having problems with a change of names in data sets, which is confusing, because I am only using one data set.

My data is organized with sites as rows and columns as species abundance. Like so:

```
        sp#2    sp#2    sp#3
site#1   5       76      4
site#2   0       23      5
site#3   86      3       87
```

I imported my data as an excel file and used the code:

```
rads <- as.data.frame(mydata, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE)
```

I am using the `RADanalysis` package in R to make a normalized matrix of my Rank Abundance Distribution (RAD) for my snail communities. I sort/plot an RAD with no problems. This all comes out as expected (something similar to this https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Abundance-distribution-Whittaker-Plot-of-four-Scarabaeidae-communities-active-in-sites_fig1_236023671).  It is when I try to normalize my data the errors start:

```
nrads <- RADnormalization_matrix(input = rads, 
              max_rank = 3, average_over = 10,
              sample_in_row = TRUE)
```

I receive this output:

```
nrads <- RADnormalization_matrix(input = rads, 
               max_rank = 3,
                average_over = 10,
               sample_in_row = TRUE)
  1 ( 8.33 %) 
 |2 ( 16.67 %) 
 |Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names
```

I am confused by this, because I did not change my data set nor am I trying to merge data sets together. I am making a new object, with the same data set, using the function `RADnormalization_matrix`. Why does R think my previous names do not match when their are no previous names?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Research article I am following: https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1005362#pcbi.1005362.e005

Comment: What would really help is if you would simplify your code to just as much as you need to get the problem (take out all of the colors and so on). Also add copy and paste-able code to read in your data or use some sample data. [mcve]

Comment: i.e. all the plotting code is irrelevant to the error, which is in the `RADnormalization_matrix` line.

Comment: I'd remove the plot tag as not relevant.   Do you have the # in your actual names? Try taking them out.

Comment: @Elin - that's my guess too. The error is probably an `rbind` call in the function, but somehow the invalid `sp#n` named columns are getting made into valid names that don't match the original input. If the names are overwritten removing `#` I'll wager a bet it works.

Comment: @thelatemail
My species' names do not have symbols or numbers in them. They are latin names like "Allopeas gracile"

Comment: I think we need a [mcve] at this point to solve the problem ...

Comment: I would simplify your input data (`rads` I guess) down to a single line/single column or whatever is the smallest feasible size.  Does it work?  If it does, add your data, line-by-line, column-by-column, until you run into the issue.  No idea what it might be here but some examples from elsewhere: expecting continuous, not integer value; factor with NA level; factor with a level of 0 observations...  Consider fileing a bug report for uninformative error message in RAD.

Comment: Hello @OttToomet, that has worked. The first time I have performed the function  RADnormalization_matrix I grouped my 12 sites into 3 broad categories. This helped me perform the normalization, but the next step over these analyses require a higher sample size. That is why I have came back to using 12 sites instead of 3 categories. 

Using the sample data the package comes with these data can be analyzed with a lot more rows I have used. 

I would try your process of adding data lines (one by one), but that would null the point of these comparisons. My bad.

Comment: Can you please update your sample code with valid row and column names in a form that someone could copy and paste to run your whole script without any extra.   So just start with creating a valid data frame.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

```
library(RADanalysis)
sp1 <- c(5, 76, 4)
sp2 <-c(0, 23, 5)
sp3 <- c(86, 3, 87)
rads <- data.frame(sp1, sp2, sp3)
RADnormalization_matrix(input = rads , 
                        max_rank = 2,
                        average_over = 10,
                       sample_in_row = TRUE
                      )
```

The key difference is I changed the max_rank to 2 (1 also worked).

I got

```
1 ( 33.33 %) |2 ( 66.67 %) |3 ( 100 %) |$norm_matrix
        sp3        sp1
1 0.9450549 0.05494505
2 0.7640106 0.23598937
3 0.8794428 0.12055721

$inputs
$inputs$min_rank
[1] 1

$inputs$max_rank
[1] 2

$inputs$average_over
[1] 10

$inputs$labels
[1] FALSE

$inputs$sample_in_row
[1] TRUE

$inputs$method
[1] "upperlimit"

$inputs$verbose
[1] TRUE
```

So I think that most likely you can't have max_rank equal to the number of columns  since this is data reduction.